# Mathematica hang on a Manipulate expression

Tags: manipulate, bugs, predictive-interface

```
Manipulate[Plot[Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[t])], {x, -5, 5}], {t, 0.1, 5}]
```

With a fresh kernel, after evaluating this, Mathematica will hang immediately if I try to drag the slide bar.

After some testing, this problem exists on 10.1 and later on my machine. Is it a bug?

My test environment: OS X 10.11.4, version 10.0.2 does not have this problem; version 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.3.1, 10.4, 10.4.1 have this problem;

on Windows 10(10240), 10.1 and 10.2 do not have this problem;
10.3 and 10.4 have this problem;

on Windows XP, version 6,7,8,9 do not have this problem.(`Manipulate` does not exist below version 6)

More observations:

For the versions with problems, consecutively evaluating the expression twice will fix it.

Comment: No problems on my *Mathematica* 10.0.2.0 Windows 64 bits

Comment: No problem with version 10.3.1 on OS X 10.11.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable "Show Suggestions Bar after last output" and be sure "Dynamic Updating Enabled". Now you can run the `Manipulate` and it works fine on Windows 10 (64 bit) and Mathematica 10.4.1.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Erfc[x/(2 Sqrt[t])], {x, -5, 5}], {t, 0.1, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Another suggestion bar bug

Comment: @happy fish You're right, it's not the only one :)